# How can I remove a dot from this input in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have built a jQuery function that will validate a CV2 field for credit cards.

The field only allows three characters
The field only allows numeric entry
The field will reset if you try to place more than 3 digits

On Chrome however, when I try to enter a digit followed by a the "." symbol, it allows me to enter, so I can enter in essence 1.22 which will show in the form as 122.

It only happens in Chrome, does the regex allow dots?

```
<input type="number" placeholder="CVV" id="cybersource_cc_cid">
```

JS:

```
function cc() {
  // -- APPLY CHANGES TO CC FIELD
  var cc = $('#cybersource_cc_cid');
  function chunksOf(string, size) {
    var i,
    j,
    arr = [
    ];
    for (i = 0, j = string.length; i < j; i += size) {
      arr.push(string.substring(i, i + size));
    }
    return arr;
  }
  cc.on('input', function () {
    var elem = cc.get(0); // store DOM element ref
    var value = cc.val().replace(/\D/g, ''); // strip non-numeric chars
    var newValue = chunksOf(value, 3); // split into 4-digit chunks
    cc.val(newValue); // update new value
  });
}
cc();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lcxk6nj/

Comment: The regex replace seems to work as what you'd expect on my version of Chrome.  What result do you get on your version if you try `chunksOf("12.3abc45,6".replace(/\D/g,""),3).toLocaleString()` in your Chrome console?

Comment: The dot will appear

Comment: Is the output between `chunksOf("1234",2).toLocaleString()` and `chunksOf("1234",2).join(",")` the same?